# Check if object ONLY contains one or two items javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a strange issue to solve, lets assume you are given a couple examples of an object that can be returned:

example 1:

```
{name: "something", age: 17, money: 700}
```

example 2:

```
{age: 17, money: 700}
```

example 3:

```
{age: 17} // Or
{money: 700}
```

So heres what I need to check for. If the object only has `age` or `money` or `age` and `money`

Is there a way using either lodash or pure javascript (prefer lodash) to say: do you contain or contain or contain and contain **and nothing else** the **and nothing else** is important.

Answer (score 2):

Try utilizing `Object.keys()` , `Array.prototype.every()`

```js
var obj1 = {
  name: "something",
  age: 17,
  money: 700
};

var obj2 = {
  age: 17,
  money: 700
}

var obj3 = {
    age: 17
  } 

// Or
var obj4 = {
  money: 700
}

var check = function(v) {
  return v === "age" || v === "money"
}

var res1 = Object.keys(obj1).every(check);

var res2 = Object.keys(obj2).every(check);

var res3 = Object.keys(obj3).every(check);

var res4 = Object.keys(obj4).every(check);

console.log(res1, res2, res3, res4)
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/t6hdkats/3

Comment: What if it has both ??? I also have that as a requirement this also, just looking at it, doesn't seem to check if these are he ONLY keys. Do you have a Jsbin or fiddle??

Comment: ok, this is the right track. get the keys and check the array. of the two values are found it it and the array size is bigger than two, you know its got more than the required keys

Comment: @KyleAdams _"What if it has both ???"_ See OP at _"If the object only has age **or** money **or** age and money"_ See updated post

Comment: @LGSon _"That appears not to work: http://jsfiddle.net/t6hdkats/1 "_ ? This is  not correct. See duplicate value `obj3` as parameter to `Object.keys()` at both `res3` , `res4` ? , adjusted to `obj4` at `res4` at https://jsfiddle.net/t6hdkats/3/

Comment: You have a typo here checking `obj3` twice, that's why the console result showed wrong: `var res4 = Object.keys(obj3).every(check);`

Comment: This code is missing the "Nothing else".  If there are more properties in the object, it will still return true.

Comment: @Will _"This code is missing the "Nothing else". If there are more properties in the object, it will still return true."_ Can create jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate ?

Comment: What if the value is undefined? Key will still exist. [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/soyuka/kxzomxzv/1/)

Comment: @soyuka _"What if the value is undefined? Key will still exist."_ ? Yes, `undefined` is a valid value

Comment: @guest271314 - I was wrong in saying more properties, it should be empty object.  I believe the OP might want true if empty object.

Comment: @Will _"I believe the OP might want true if empty object."_ ? What is "empty object" ? Can indicate text at Question where `true` should be returned where "empty object" found ?

Comment: @Will No, OP wants _If the object only has `age` or `money` or `age` and `money`_

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is not my strongest skill so I'm sure this can be optimized.

```
var a = {name: "something", age: 17, money: 700};

if(Object.keys(a).length == 1 && (a.hasOwnProperty("age") || a.hasOwnProperty("money")) || (Object.keys(a).length == 2 && a.hasOwnProperty("age") && a.hasOwnProperty("money"))) {
  // yes
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Object.keys(any_obj).length` to get the number of `keys` in an object.

```
var x = {name: "something", age: 17, money: 700};
var obj = Object.keys(x);

if((obj.length==2 && x.hasOwnProperty("age") && x.hasOwnProperty("money")) || (obj.length==1 && (x.hasOwnProperty("age") || x.hasOwnProperty("money")))){
    // Condition met.
}
```

Comment: Use hasOwnProperty, otherwise x.age=0 or x.money=0 would fail this test.

Comment: @ChrisGciso `x= {age:0};` then even `x.hasOwnProperty("age")` will return true.

Comment: @void It will, but your comparison will not!

Comment: As it should per the OP.

Comment: @void - That's the point, if you test x.age and it's 0, you'll get false, but x. hasOwnProperty('age') will return true.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements are not very clear but I think this is what you are trying to do, or you may need to change the logic a little if I haven't understood your requirement correctly.

```js
function customTest(obj, list) {
  var keys = Object.keys(obj);
  var uniq = _.unique(list);
  if (!uniq.length || !keys.length && !uniq.length) {
    return true;
  }
  if (!keys.length || keys.length > uniq.length) {
    return false;
  }
  if (keys.length === uniq.length) {
    return _.isEqual(keys, uniq);
  }
  return uniq.some(function(item) {
    return !_.includes(keys, item);
  });
}

var out = document.getElementById('out');

out.textContent += customTest({}, ['age', 'money']) + '\n'; // false

out.textContent += customTest({
  name: "something",
  age: 17,
  money: 700
}, []) + '\n'; // true

out.textContent += customTest({
  name: "something",
  age: 17,
  money: 700
}, ['age', 'money']) + '\n'; // false

out.textContent += customTest({
  name: "something",
  age: 17,
  money: 700
}, ['age', 'age']) + '\n'; // false

out.textContent += customTest({
  age: 17,
}, ['age', 'age']) + '\n'; // true

out.textContent += customTest({
  name: "something",
  age: 17,
  money: 700
}, ['age', 'oranges']) + '\n'; // false

out.textContent += customTest({
  age: 17,
  money: 700
}, ['age', 'money']) + '\n'; // true

out.textContent += customTest({
  age: 17
}, ['age', 'money']) + '\n'; // true

out.textContent += customTest({
  money: 700
}, ['age', 'money']) + '\n'; // true
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/lodash/lodash-compat/3.10.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
<pre id="out"></pre>
```

You may be able to be more `lodash`y if you were a little clearer. And of course you could use `_.keys` and `_.some` in the above instead of `Object.keys` and `Array.prototype.some`